# What is it called when you change notes rapidly on one word?

Tags: voice, terminology

In *Heathers: The Musical* there are a couple times this happens:

- It happens at the very end of "Beautiful" when Veronica sings "yea", and
- It happens in "Candy Shop" when Heather Chandler sings. She doesn't really sing a word, but she goes between a bunch if notes.

I want to get better at them but I don't know what they are called.

Answer (score 14):

It sounds like you're referring to [Melisma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melisma). Technically, it goes back to the middle ages and can refer to any time multiple notes are packed into a single sung syllable, but the term "melismatic vocals" is often used specifically to refer to the modern singing style associated with Mariah Carey, Whitney Houston, and other pop/soul/gospel vocalists.